# Unable to build latest Freeswitch on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: compiler-errors, osx-lion, freeswitch

I am getting this error when trying to build Freeswitch's latest code on git on Mac OSX Lion, after fresh checkout and running ./boostraph.sh and ./configure:

```
making all mod_amr 
Creating mod_amr.so... 
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -bundle not allowed with -dynamiclib 
gcc -I/usr/local/src/freeswitch/libs/curl/include -I/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/include -I/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/include -I/usr/local/src/freeswitch/libs/libteletone/src -Werror -fvisibility=hidden -DSWITCH_API_VISIBILITY=1 -DHAVE_VISIBILITY=1 -g -ggdb -DMACOSX -DHAVE_OPENSSL -g -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -Wdeclaration-after-statement -D_GNU_SOURCE -DAMR_PASSTHROUGH -shared -o .libs/mod_amr.so -dynamic -bundle -force-flat-namespace .libs/mod_amr.o /usr/local/src/freeswitch/.libs/libfreeswitch.dylib -lodbc -lresolv -L/usr/local/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib -lpq /usr/local/src/freeswitch/libs/apr-util/xml/expat/lib/.libs/libexpat.a /usr/local/src/freeswitch/libs/apr/.libs/libapr-1.a -lpthread -lm -L/usr/local/src/freeswitch/libs/srtp -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lncurses /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib /usr/local/lib/libodbc.dylib -liconv 
make[5]: *** [mod_amr.so] Error 1 
make[4]: *** [all] Error 1 
make[3]: *** [mod_amr-all] Error 1 
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I go about commenting out offending modules, the same "bundle not allowed with -dynamiclib" appears for any number of other mods. I have installed all the prerequisites for Mac OSX (to my knowledge), including Apple and Unix dev tools. I am 100% macports/fink/brew free, AFAIK.

My sense this is a missing tool or config issue with my setup (pretty much fresh Lion install). Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a problem with the Freeswitch build system. It is supplying two mutually exclusive flags, `-bundle` and `-dynamiclib`, to the compiler.

You might want to look at their bug tracker and perhaps file a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I've filed a bug while ago, but no response: http://jira.freeswitch.org/browse/FS-4240

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, though from a different origin. I was compiling Cython, with some extra `CFLAGS` for an external library I am linking to. Those flags included `shared`, whereas `Cython` included `-bundle` automatically (compiling using `distutils` from inside a `setup.py`).

The `-shared` flag did not appear explicitly in the options, which was perplexing. Following [this suggestion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyvlfeat/+bug/1150009/comments/3) to remove the `-shared` option resolved the issue.

Noted also for anyone who is lead here by Googling this error for using `Cython`.